# How would I create a list of sub-folders in a given folder without the full path?

Tags: command-line, files

The following in a bash script:

```
find /Volumes/SpeedyG -type d >> file.txt
```

...works well to list the folders in that path in a text file,

```
/Volumes/SpeedyG/folder1  
/Volumes/SpeedyG/folder2  
/Volumes/SpeedyG/folder2
```

but the results are the full path to the folder.

What if I just wanted the folder name without the full path?

```
folder1  
folder2  
folder3
```

Answer (score 6):

For the GNU implementation of `find`, you can do this using the formatted output action `printf`:

```
          %P     File's name with the name  of  the  starting-point  under
                 which it was found removed.
```

So

```
find /Volumes/SpeedyG -type d -printf '%P\n' >> file.txt
```

---

If you want to remove *all* leading directory components, you can use `%f` instead of `%P`. If you have `zsh`, you can do the same using recursive shell globbing and the `:t` (tail) qualifier:

```
print -rC1 /Volumes/SpeedyG/**/*(ND/:t)
```

in which case you don't need `find` at all. With any POSIX `sh`, you could always do

```
find dir -type d -exec sh -c '
  for f do printf "%s\n" "${f##*/}"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: I must have a syntax problem.  If I run this from my mac terminal I get `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`  Perhaps it's different in OSX than it is in Ubuntu.

Comment: @JonGriffith: yes, this seems to be the case: https://superuser.com/a/293200/238733, and here a more up-to-date answer (2020 instead of 2011): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61158594/2375855

Comment: @JonGriffith If you're seeking answers for OSX rather than Ubuntu, [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is a much better place for asking. [Superuser SE](https://superuser.com/) also could work.

Answer (score 0):

`tree -di /Volumes/SpeedyG` will give you a list of only subfolders.

`tree -dia /Volumes/SpeedyG` will give you a list of only subfolders to include hidden directories.

`tree -diL 1 /Volumes/SpeedyG` will give you a list of only subfolders 1 level in.

note: if a directory is a symbolic link to another directory, then that line of output will show the link and path to the target directory...
You could eliminate it with a grep statement like `tree -di /Volumes/SpeedyG | grep -v "\->"`

Comment: I would prefer a result that trims the leading path so I only get everything to the right of SpeedyG/

Comment: @JonGriffith To be clear, what you are saying is, if you did `tree -di /Volumes/SpeedyG > sampletext.txt`... And you look at sampletext.txt, the only thing that is undesired in the file, is the very first line in it... correct?

Comment: No.  Each line in the txt file refers to the full path of the files that were added to the txt, i.e. /Volumes/SpeedyG/folder1.  I would like the resulting list to be trimmed to only show a list of all of the folders found at this level, so the list would be "folder1, folder2, folder3" etc.

Comment: @JonGriffith ...I don't have the same results that you are seeing.. all i see is one subdirectory name per line... As a matter of fact, if I wanted to see the full path I would have to do `tree -fdi /Volumes/SpeedyG` instead... But now that you mentioned "at this level", I will edit for anyone else that would find that useful. Don't know what to say about why you are seeing what you are seeing though.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `basename` removes any leading directory components from a full pathname.

```
$ basename /Volumes/SpeedyG/folder1
folder1
```

To process multiple pathnames, use the `--multiple` option:

```
‘-a’
‘--multiple’
     Support more than one argument.  Treat every argument as a NAME.
     With this, an optional SUFFIX must be specified using the ‘-s’
     option.

$ basename -a /Volumes/SpeedyG/folder1 /Volumes/SpeedyG/folder2 /Volumes/SpeedyG/folder3
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

---

In a script, a more efficient way of stripping off the largest prefix is to resort to parameter expansion like so:

```
file="/Volumes/SpeedyG/folder1"
file="${file##/*/}"
```

You can utilize this in a `for` loop:

```
for i in /Volumes/SpeedyG/*
do
    printf "%s\n" "${i##/*/}"
done > $HOME/files.txt

$ cat ~/files.txt
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

Comment: basename -a $(ls -d1 $SOME_DIR_PATH/*/)